# passing parameters into sql insert

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2, ejs

I have an insert query, where i am inserting a string into my db2 database, but the string may include `" or '`. could I use parameters for inserting to get around this issue?

```
var addProducts = "insert into PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, IMAGE ) VALUES ('" +
  req.query.item +
  "', '" +
  req.query.description +
  "', '" +
  req.query.price +
  "', '" +
  size +
  "', '" +
  image_url +
  "' )";
```

that is what I have right now... thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will be useful for you:

Using `` and ${}:

```
var addProducts = `INSERT INTO PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, IMAGE ) VALUES (${req.query.item}, ${req.query.description}, ${req.query.price}, ${size}, ${image_url} )`;
```

In the types diff to string add .toString():

```
req.query.price.toString();
size.toString();
```

And if you require the quotation mark:

```
var addProducts = `INSERT INTO PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, IMAGE ) VALUES ('${req.query.item}', '${req.query.description}', '${req.query.price}', '${size}', '${image_url}' )`;
```

In addition you can scape quotation marks in the string with \

```
const str = "\"\'";



var addProducts = `INSERT INTO PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, IMAGE ) VALUES (\'${req.query.item}\', \'${req.query.description}\', \'${req.query.price}\', \'${size}\', \'${image_url}\' )`;
```

I did this exercise:

```
sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    var stringRequest = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, IMAGE) VALUES ("+ req.query.item +","+ req.query.description +","+ req.query.price+","+ size +","+image_url+" )";
    request.query(stringRequest, function(err, recordset) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
    });
});
```

Comment: hi! this didn't work for me unfortunately, it actually still gave me the same error, but more times then before now on a few of the values...

Comment: Ho, sorry. I added an exercise, i hope it helps. In case the error still, can you send me the error? and the other part of code to have more ideas. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this probleme and all kind of SQL Injection you should use query parameters and let the drive bind the variable to the parameters.

take a look at:
[3) .query(sqlQuery [, bindingParameters], callback)](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/blob/master/APIDocumentation.md)